# Macro to autofilter across different sheets and paste result on a different sheet

Tags: macros

I need to create autofilter across 3 sheets based on values selected on the three dropdown lists on a separate sheet on the same workbook.  The 3 sheets have the same headers from columns A to AG and i need to filter across these three sheets and paste the result on a separate sheet on the same workbook.  On the other sheet with the dropdown lists, I need to select three options to filter different columns simulatenously. The 3 dropdown lists are Name, Period (Date) and Status (New,Completed and Current Open Items)

The columns that I need to filter are column A (name), for the date columns either column U or column V depending on the selected value in the dropdown list Period mentioned above. I also need to filter all the current open items when it is selected in the Status dropdown list.

What I want to do are the following scenarios:
 1.) If I select from the dropdown lists the Name, Period and Status = "New", the data in the three sheets will filter column A (name) and column U (date of new items) if they match with the dropdown selections.

2.) If I select from the dropdown lists the Name, Period and Status = "Completed", the data in the three sheets will filter column A (name) and column V (date of completed items) if they match with the dropdown selections.

3.) If I select from the dropdown list the Name, Period and Status = "Current Open Items", the data in the three sheets will filter column A (name) and column L.

I also need the filtered results be captured on a separate sheet on the same workbook and the workbook to automatically refresh when there are changes in the data and to delete existing filtered data when filtering for new selections. Hope you could help me on this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If this is Microsoft Excel, I recommend posting your question over at mrexcel.com.

They are going to probably suggest you attach the spreadsheet in question to your post to facilitate and understanding of the problem.